# Windows Integrated account is slow to connect to the SQL server database.

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a SQL server that belongs to a domain and an application server that is stand alone. Of course it has the right ROUTES to reach the sql server.
when I use a test.udl file to test the connection, a sql login would work right away. But if we try a windows integrated account (servername\username) it takes about 25 seconds to connect.

Unfortunately I have MSMQ running on that server and application that has to take these messages and send it to the SQL server. Because of the delay (I think) MSMQ keeps all its messages.

Do you know what could be the reason for this delay only on WIndows integrated logins?

Note that, I have windows firewall disabled on these servers, No Antivirus.
SQL Server 2008 R2.
Application Server - Windows 2008 R2

Thanks for your time,

RM

Comment: in the post i read 'servername\username' and not 'domain\username'. the user you are logging on as is a domain user or a local user on one of the 2 server?

Comment: Its servername\username. It is the way our application is setup. Localusers are created on application server and sql server. And those users have access to relevant databases.

Comment: what about the event log? did you look for any event related to authentication?

Comment: A SQL Login is stored directly on the SQL server and never needs to make a call to your domain server so it should always be faster. I wouldn't automatically assume that your problem is on your database. Windows Auth accounts bump credentials against your Active Directory so by switching from SQL Auth to Windows Auth you've just introduced a number of new failure points to your architecture. I would recommend  a packet sniffer like WireShark to see the calls going out from your App Server and coming in to your SQL Server. You might have a network issue on your hands.

Comment: Thanks all. Would you it check the DC even though those are local accounts?

Comment: answered here : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104378/sql-server-management-studio-slow-connection-or-timeout-when-using-windows-authe , change host file add ip and computer name